# JMS configuration issue in OpenLiberty 21.0.0.5

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, open-liberty

I have tried JMS in my sample project. When [using a single](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee8-starter-boilerplate/blob/master/src/main/liberty/config/server.xml#L45-L55) queue it works well, e.g.:

```xml
    <messagingEngine>
        <queue id="HelloQueue"/>
    </messagingEngine>

    <jmsQueue id="jms/HelloQueue" jndiName="java:app/jms/HelloQueue">
        <properties.wasJms queueName="HelloQueue"/>
    </jmsQueue>

    <jmsActivationSpec id="jakartaee8-starter/HelloConsumer">
        <properties.wasJms
                destinationRef="jms/HelloQueue"
                destinationType="javax.jms.Queue"
        />
    </jmsActivationSpec>
```

However, when I tried to add a [series of queues](https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker/blob/openliberty-config/src/main/liberty/config/server.xml#L34-L88) it does not work, e.g.

```xml
    <messagingEngine>
        <queue id="MisdirectedCargoQueue"/>
        <queue id="CargoHandledQueue"/>
        <queue id="RejectedRegistrationAttemptsQueue"/>
        <queue id="HandlingEventRegistrationAttemptQueue"/>
        <queue id="DeliveredCargoQueue"/>
    </messagingEngine>

    <jmsQueue id="jms/MisdirectedCargoQueue" jndiName="java:app/jms/MisdirectedCargoQueue">
        <properties.wasJms queueName="MisdirectedCargoQueue"/>
    </jmsQueue>
    <jmsQueue id="jms/CargoHandledQueue" jndiName="java:app/jms/CargoHandledQueue">
        <properties.wasJms queueName="CargoHandledQueue"/>
    </jmsQueue>
    <jmsQueue id="jms/RejectedRegistrationAttemptsQueue" jndiName="java:app/jms/RejectedRegistrationAttemptsQueue">
        <properties.wasJms queueName="RejectedRegistrationAttemptsQueue"/>
    </jmsQueue>
    <jmsQueue id="jms/HandlingEventRegistrationAttemptQueue" jndiName="java:app/jms/HandlingEventRegistrationAttemptQueue">
        <properties.wasJms queueName="HandlingEventRegistrationAttemptQueue"/>
    </jmsQueue>
    <jmsQueue id="jms/DeliveredCargoQueue" jndiName="java:app/jms/DeliveredCargoQueue">
        <properties.wasJms queueName="DeliveredCargoQueue"/>
    </jmsQueue>

    <jmsActivationSpec id="cargo-tracker/MisdirectedCargoConsumer">
        <properties.wasJms
                destinationRef="jms/MisdirectedCargoQueue"
                destinationType="javax.jms.Queue"
        />
    </jmsActivationSpec>
    <jmsActivationSpec id="cargo-tracker/CargoHandledConsumer">
        <properties.wasJms
                destinationRef="jms/CargoHandledQueue"
                destinationType="javax.jms.Queue"
        />
    </jmsActivationSpec>
    <jmsActivationSpec id="cargo-tracker/RejectedRegistrationAttemptsConsumer">
        <properties.wasJms
                destinationRef="jms/RejectedRegistrationAttemptsQueue"
                destinationType="javax.jms.Queue"
        />
    </jmsActivationSpec>
    <jmsActivationSpec id="cargo-tracker/HandlingEventRegistrationAttemptConsumer">
        <properties.wasJms
                destinationRef="jms/HandlingEventRegistrationAttemptQueue"
                destinationType="javax.jms.Queue"
        />
    </jmsActivationSpec>
    <jmsActivationSpec id="cargo-tracker/DeliveredCargoConsumer">
        <properties.wasJms
                destinationRef="jms/DeliveredCargoQueue"
                destinationType="javax.jms.Queue"
        />
    </jmsActivationSpec>
```

When running the application I get:

```sh
[INFO] [WARNING ] CNTR4016W: The message endpoint for the CargoHandledConsumer message-driven bean cannot be activated because the java:app/jms/CargoHandledQueue destination is not available. The message endpoint will not receive messages until the destination becomes available.
[INFO] [WARNING ] CNTR4016W: The message endpoint for the RejectedRegistrationAttemptsConsumer message-driven bean cannot be activated because the java:app/jms/RejectedRegistrationAttemptsQueue destination is not available. The message endpoint will not receive messages until the destination becomes available.
[INFO] [WARNING ] CNTR4016W: The message endpoint for the MisdirectedCargoConsumer message-driven bean cannot be activated because the java:app/jms/MisdirectedCargoQueue destination is not available. The message endpoint will not receive messages until the destination becomes available.
[INFO] [WARNING ] CNTR4016W: The message endpoint for the HandlingEventRegistrationAttemptConsumer message-driven bean cannot be activated because the java:app/jms/HandlingEventRegistrationAttemptQueue destination is not available. The message endpoint will not receive messages until the destination becomes available.
[INFO] [WARNING ] CNTR4016W: The message endpoint for the DeliveredCargoConsumer message-driven bean cannot be activated because the java:app/jms/DeliveredCargoQueue destination is not available. The message endpoint will not receive messages until the destination becomes available.
```

Answer (score 4):

its the id in jmsQueue that's confusing matters, a better initial example would be

```
<messagingEngine>
     <queue id="HelloQueue"/>
 </messagingEngine>

 <jmsQueue jndiName="jms/HelloQueue">
     <properties.wasJms queueName="HelloQueue"/>
 </jmsQueue>

     <jmsActivationSpec id="jakartaee8-starter/HelloConsumer">
         <properties.wasJms
                 destinationRef="jms/HelloQueue"
         />
 </jmsActivationSpec>
```

There are some more examples here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=server-configuring-point-point-messaging-single-liberty

Comment: Almost all `xxxRef` properties in the Openliberty docs refer to an `id`,  https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.5/reference/config/jmsActivationSpec.html, and there is another `distinationLookup` property to look up the object by JNDI name. It is very confusing, the open liberty reference does not provide example codes.